# Should I avoid establishing a MySQL Connection (when using Memcache) or is establishing the connection anyway the way to go?

Tags: mysql, optimization, memcached

so I am just getting started using Memcache. I am ready to write some code, however I have an optimization question:

I wonder whether I should delay establishing a MySQL Connect as far as possible (and maybe not establish one at all, when everything can be read from the Memcache) OR establish it anyway to spare me coding time, based on the thought that not the connection but the actual querys make my server's CPU go crazy.

So, I have to choose between these two code examples:

## 1 - Connect to MySQL anyway

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("MEMCACHE: Could not connect!");
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password') or die ("MySQL: Could not connect!");
mysql_select_db('database');

$sql = "SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 1";
$key = md5('query'.$sql);
//lookup value in memcache
$result = $memcache->get($key);
//check if we got something back
if($result == null) {
//fetch from database
$qry = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()." : $sql");
if(mysql_num_rows($qry)> 0) {
    $result = mysql_fetch_object($qry);
    //store in memcache for 60 seconds
    $memcache->set($key,$result,0,60);
   }
}
```

## 2 - Connect to MySQL as soon as it is needed

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("MEMCACHE: Could not connect!");

$sql = "SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 1";
$key = md5('query'.$sql);
//lookup value in memcache
$result = $memcache->get($key);
//check if we got something back
if($result == null) {

if(!$db){
    $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password') or die ("MySQL: Could not connect!");
    mysql_select_db('database');
}

//fetch from database
$qry = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()." : $sql");
if(mysql_num_rows($qry)> 0) {
    $result = mysql_fetch_object($qry);
    //store in memcache for 60 seconds
    $memcache->set($key,$result,0,60);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go is to connect to mySQL(and other stuff) only when you need it. that way you reduce the resources your app needs in this case network connections. and you don't put a load to the DB server.

General rule of thumb : use a resource only when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

If speed is important, get the connection up front. It's not a big resource to have open, but it can take a while to establish.

Also, by connecting early you know on app startup if there's a problem (eg database server down) and you get confirmation that everything is good to go, rather than exuding some time later when you could have known earlier and fixed the problem before it was becme problem.

You might want to go further and run a heartbeat query to assert that the database is still there so similar reasons.

Note that this approach makes the database *required* to be up for your app to be up. You can do something in between: get the connection at startup, but if it`s not available fall back to a just in time approach, which gives you more flexibility. This is what I'd do.

Comment: that effect is not that desirable , if you store your data in memcache you will be able to at least serve a read only version of your site ( assuming you mostly have reads) and you will show errors only when writes are done, which is more preferable. as for site being up , you should have some sort of monitoring of your servers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on concurrency. But cache the connections in a thread safe pool is better.

In many web applications, database connections are established and put in a thread safe pool, because establishing a connection is expensive.

It seems like getting data from memcached not directly from database, because it more fast and can hold so many threads.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you provided (usual last-century-style spaghetti) I'd vote for the first one.
Whatever logic added to the program flow will make your code more complex by a factor of ten. So, better leave it as plain as possible.

Or, even, I would advise not to use memcache at all, until you learn how to separate and encapsulate different matters.
Especially because there is no point in caching data you can get from db by the primary key.